# Why does Django Admin shows empty dropdown on foreign key field to multi-inheritance model?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin, multi-table-inheritance

I have the following models:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Content(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=2000)

class Document(Content):
    file = models.FileField()
    reading_time = models.IntegerField()

class DocumentView(BaseModel):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    viewed_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Everything works as expected, except that in the Django Admin, editing a DocumentView model, the Document dropdown doesn't get selected with the saved Document.

Regarding the Admin, I use it in the default way:

```
admin.site.register(DocumentView)
```

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot too ?

Comment: There's a screenshot

Comment: I removed "Training" field from the code example for clarity

Comment: `viewed_on` is on admin site!! How could that possible if  `auto_now=True`. Am I wrong? (not related to your question, though)

Comment: If that `Document` drop-down has no elements, it means you don't have any `Document` instances currently in `DB`. To create new `Document` instance **via Django Admin**, use that **+** button, and add info related to your `Document` model. Did this solve your issue?

Comment: Hi Jerin, thanks for your answer. Actually, a few `Documents` exists already and are loaded on the dropdown. The screenshot was taken from an "edit" screen, not a "create", so this `DocumentView` already exists on the DB and has a Document assigned. The problem is that when I go to edit that `DocumentView`, the dropdown does not select the right `Document` and shows blank.

Comment: This problem started happening when I created the "Content" base model